# JBOSS server throwing exception -cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager

Tags: java, maven, jboss, weblogic

We are migrating Weblogic 12C server to JBOSS 7 and while testing the application, the following exception occured:

> Exception occured during xpath Evalution : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager

We have Xalan.jar (2.6.0)packaged in war file under web-inf folder. It seems the JBOSS server does not have a module set for xalan jar so it should be present only through our .war file.

Could you please explain to me why this exception occurred?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have multiple JAXP library in your war/container environment. `Xalan` (as you can see [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673)) is already provided on container level (version **2.7.1** for `JBoss 7`). Try to remove the dependency from your project (just set it to `<scope>provided</scope>`) and redeploy.